# Visual Studio Code: use "go to definition", on methods that were added manually to the prototype

Tags: oop, visual-studio-code, composition

I really like the go to definition(alt+click) feature of Visual Studio Code. The problem is, it doesn't work on functions that were added to some class by using Object.assign or some similar way. For example:

```
const DigestiveBehavior = require('./DigestiveBehavior');
const Animal = require('./Animal');

class Dog extends Animal{
constructor(name){
    super();
    this.name = name;
    Object.assign(Dog.prototype,DigestiveBehavior.prototype)//I use 
     "composition" here to give Dog additional functionality.
  }
}
```

This is DigestiveBehavior "trait", which Dog uses:

```
function DigestiveBehavior(){

}

 DigestiveBehavior.prototype={
  eat:function(){
     console.log(this.name,' eating!');
    }
 }
```

This is the code that uses it:

```
 const dog = new Dog('good doggie');
 dog.eat();
```

Of course this all works, but Visual Code doesn't recognize the definition source of the dog.eat() method when i alt+click it, being that it's not defined in the class. Is there any plugin or a workaround to make the IDE do that?

Answer (score 0):

This code is not composition:

```
class Dog extends Animal{
    constructor(name){
        super();
        this.name = name;
        Object.assign(Dog.prototype,DigestiveBehavior.prototype)//I use 
         //"composition" here to give Dog additional functionality.
    }
}
```

Basically what you are doing here is this, but "manually":

```
class Dog extends Animal  {
    Bark(): void {}
}
```

The above code should have the same result, however, the IDE will know about the methods of "Animal"